# AngularJS Output filtered variable

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/KPMUOp16FAArgx1GsnEx?p=preview

Looking at the code, the first array of variables corresponds to a list of radio boxes. When you click on any of them, it creates a second radio box list. The radio boxes on the second list are created by filtering out a second array based on the first selection. `Debug` shows first selection. What I'm trying to do is display a variable that corresponds to a radio box that you select from the filtered list.

So you click `"Apple"`, a radio box list of of `"Red"` and `"Yellow"` appears. If I was to click on Red, `Debug2` should show `red` - variable from `$scope.employees` array.

Ideas?

Comment: Where is the checkbox? `Debug` seems to be doing the same thing as your requirement - why are you looking for `Debug2`?

Comment: If you click on `"Apple"` a set of check boxes appear. If I click on them, I want their variables to be passed to `Debug2`.

Comment: Please edit your question then with this information. It is not clear from the current question the problem that you face..

Answer (score 2):

Create in controller the model:

```
$scope.selectedSub =$scope.employees[0].value;
```

After, add the model to radio-buttons:

```
<div ng-repeat="emploee in employees | filter:filterFunctions.forWorkspace(filtering.workspace_id)">
      <input type="radio" 
      value="{{emploee.value}}"
      ng-model="$parent.selectedSub"
      name="{{emploee.name}}">{{emploee.sub_text}}</input>
```

See Demo in <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4nMHQghLg8vsoNlmKmsw?p=preview)</kbd>

Comment: Hm. Is there a way to combine `selectedSub` and `filtering` under one model. The output in this case would be `{"workspace_id": "A", "selectedSub": "red"}`

Comment: I don't think so. Each item in `ng-repeat` directive has its own scope. So if you want to use one of elements out of loop, it should be object *predefined* in controller

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in controller to set value for Debug2

```
$scope.Debug2val="";
  $scope.setDebug2val=function(val)
  {
    $scope.Debug2val=val;
  }
```

Then in HTML pass the radio button text to the above method on ng-click event.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yaseed/CKuGB/)

Comment: Good call on the ng-click!